# Having a common setup function for tests

Tags: testing, installation, nose, teardown

So I have a script test.py

```
from nose.tools import with_setup

class Test:
    @with_setup(setup_func, teardown_func)
    def test(self):
        print "Hello World"
```

Can I have setup_func() and teardown_func() defined in an **init**.py in the same directory as "test.py".

Basically, the objective is to have a common setup and teardown for a bunch of test cases.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing magical about `setup_func` and `teardown_func`. You can certainly do that by importing them from any module, if it called `init.py` or `__init__`. I would suggest you put it in some other module, say `test_setup.py` because you may not want to have those definitions at the package level of the test module, and "explicit is better than implicit" philosophy will be enforced.

**ADDED:** However, you have a bigger problem here: `with_setup` is useful only for test functions, not for test methods or inside of subclasses. As written, in your code, your `setup` function will not be called regardless where it is specified, see [here](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing_tools.html).

If you intend to make your tests as class methods, you would have to rely on `setUp` and `tearDown` methods of the [unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html). If you wish, you can inherit your test class from a special setup class and reuse this same special class again for different tests.

Comment: wow I never knew that I could import from __init__.py to some other module.. is that true?

Comment: why cant I find anything online which confirms that?